# CSS hidden:overflow not working with absolute position?

Tags: html, css

I have a circle with some `<div>` in it.
I want to hide overflow of this `<div>` using `overflow:hidden` property.

This is the result:

[image]

As you can see, div is not hidden at all. However, after removing  `position:absolute` from inner `<div>`, it looks like this:

[image]

Now, the `<div>` is properly cropped, but the outer `<div>` is now an ellipse rather than a circle.

How can I have a circle with properly cropped inner `<div>`?

#### My code:

```css
.button-circle {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);
  background-size: cover;
}
.button-circle div {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="button-circle">
  <div>
    <h3>Click me!</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should know that border-radius has not needed prefixes for quite some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `.button-circle`

```css
.button-circle {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.button-circle div {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="button-circle">
  <div>
    <h3>Click me!</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two solutions for your problem, depending on whether you do or don't want absolute positioning for the inner `<div>`.

---

#### Without `position:abolute`

If you want it to work without `position:abolute` on your `.button-circle div`, you'll need to add `float:left;` to that selector and adjust the padding of your `.button-circle` :

```css
.button-circle {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 80%;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);
  background-size: cover;
}
.button-circle div {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="button-circle">
  <div>
    <h3>Click me!</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/y43f6aqd/))

---

#### With `position:abolute`

If you want it to work with `position:abolute` on your `.button-circle div`, you'll need to add `position: relative;` to your `.button-circle` selector :

```css
.button-circle {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.button-circle div {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="button-circle">
  <div>
    <h3>Click me!</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/y43f6aqd/1/))